# Burninate [reservation] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reservation

This tag has 0 followers, the major users of this tag have <100 rep, most questions are either closed as off topic or have negative votes, burninate?

Comment: You proposed the quickest burn I've seen ;)

Comment: I was very curious why "reservation" had anything to do with programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
quickest burnination in history, all posts gone from the tag, it will die overnight.

---

There's now 2 closed questions with the tag, with at least one delete vote each that can easily be deleted from the site.